# How to break line of list in list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to show the list like matrix, but I couldn't line break..
how can I show this list as matrix without numpy.
I used join, but it doesn't work..

provided data(txt file) as following:

ControlPoint Longitude Latitude

```
A 30 0

B 60 0

C 60 -30

D 30 -30
```

```
import math

Coordi = []    
with open('2432004k_coordi_new.txt') as D:
    for item in D:
        Coordi.append([i for i in item.split()])
        Coordi = Coordi.join("\n")

print ("Coordi=")
print Coordi
```

```
Coordi =

[[ 30.   0.]

 [ 60.   0.]

 [ 60. -30.]

 [ 30. -30.]]
```

Comment: Could you provide us an example for wished output?

Comment: Cordi is a list. ```Cordi.join('\n')``` will not work as ```join``` is a string method.

Comment: The below matrix is what I want, but I failed..

Comment: why not use `numpy`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it printed like that and you don't want to use numpy, you should write your own print function.
It could be something like:

```
def prettyprint(m):
    print("[",m[0])
    i = 1
    while i < len(m) - 1:
        print(" ", m[i])
        i += 1
    print(" ", m[i], "]")
```

and then call it on your matrix.

If you want better inner formatting, you could always iterate over the rows and print each value the way you want it to be displayed. Something like:

```
print("[", end="")
for val in row:
    print(val, " ", end="")  # to not print a newline char
print("]", end="")
```